# Ant.design Autocomplete error when search by a number

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I'm working with ant design to create a more complex autocomplete component. I need to search and show multiple data columns. 
At this example, I got two columns called tax_id and legal_name. The user could search by both. When I start the autocomplete search with a letter, there's no problem, but when I start the search with a number (to search by tax_id) Ant design shows me an error.

I've tried parsing the input value to string but nothing happens, I think it could be the `filterOption` Method. This method passes two parameters (value, option). Value is the current value of the input field, and the option is the DOM Node. I use both, the first one to compare, and the second one to enter the content inside autocomplete value. I cannot use the `filterOption` default value `true` because I have a children component inside with divs to separate the content.

```
<AutoComplete
  value={this.state.inputEnterprise}
  onSearch={val => {
    console.log(val);
    this.setState({
      inputEnterprise: val
    });
  }}
  onSelect={(val, opt) => {
    this.setState({
      inputEnterprise: opt.props.children.props.children[0]
    });
  }}
  filterOption={(val, opt) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < opt.props.children.props.children.length; i++) {
      const p = opt.props.children.props.children[i];
      if (
        p.props.children.toLowerCase().includes(val.toString().toLowerCase())
      ) {
        return true;
      }
    }
  }}
>
  {children}
</AutoComplete>;
```

the Children component

```
const children = this.state.listOfEnterprises.map((s, i) => {
            return (
                <Option className="qwe" key={i}>
                    <div className="separator">
                        {this.state.keys.map((k, i) => {
                            return <div key={i}>{s[k]}</div>
                        })}
                    </div>
                </Option>
            )
        })
```

PS: the keys mapping only is an array of two elements in this case, to obtain the keys in an array of objects

```
this.state = {
    ...
    keys: ['tax_id', 'legal_name'],
}
```

**Here's a codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/r-u4ko5**
When I type a string, all is correct (as you can see, I got two divs, one with the tax_id, another with legal_name)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/op42K.png

When I type an integer, automatically input shows [Object object]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KdShJ.png

The index.js:171 shows a console.log with the number that I wrote. but after that, raise this error
https://i.stack.imgur.com/IfZ4e.png

And shows the next error

```
Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `inputValue` of type `object` supplied to `DropdownMenu`, expected `string`.
    in DropdownMenu (created by SelectTrigger)
    in SelectTrigger (created by Select)
    in Select (created by Context.Consumer)
    in Select (created by Context.Consumer)
    in AutoComplete (at recepcion/index.js:168)
    in div (created by Context.Consumer)
    in Col (at recepcion/index.js:157)
    in div (created by Context.Consumer)
    in Row (at recepcion/index.js:128)
    in div (created by Context.Consumer)
    in StyledComponent (created by styled.div)
    in styled.div (at recepcion/index.js:127)
    in div (at recepcion/index.js:113)
    in Recepcion (created by ConnectFunction)
    in ConnectFunction (created by Context.Consumer)
    in div (at PanelLayout.js:18)
    in section (at PanelLayout.js:17)
    in div (at PanelLayout.js:13)
    in div (at PanelLayout.js:8)
    in PanelLayout (created by Context.Consumer)
    in Route (at RouteWithLayout.js:6)
    in RouteWithLayout (at routes/index.js:20)
    in Switch (at routes/index.js:13)
    in Unknown (at App.js:29)
    in div (created by Context.Consumer)
    in StyledComponent (created by styled.div)
    in styled.div (at App.js:28)
    in Provider (at App.js:27)
    in Router (created by HashRouter)
    in HashRouter (at App.js:26)
    in App (at src/index.js:7) index.js:1375
    e index.js:1375
    printWarning checkPropTypes.js:21
    checkPropTypes checkPropTypes.js:76
    React 2
    getDropdownElement SelectTrigger.js:191
    render SelectTrigger.js:273
    React 12
    unstable_runWithPriority scheduler.development.js:255
    React 3
```

Comment: Please make a sandbox example - like https://codesandbox.io/s/new it much easier to help when people having code to play with

Comment: @DennisVash I appreciate your comment. I added a sandbox with the problem. https://codesandbox.io/s/r-u4ko5

Comment: Check your sandbox it has errors

Comment: By looking on your code I think you overthinking, do you only trying to autocomplete the enterprises?

Answer (score 0):

`Option` values need to be of type `string`, in your case `tax_id` is a `number` so you need to convert it - `<div key={i}>{String(s[k])}</div>`.

Here is a simplified working example of your code:

[image]

```js
const dataSource = [
  {
    tax_id: 123,
    legal_name: 'asd'
  },
  {
    tax_id: 456,
    legal_name: 'qwe'
  }
];

const taxIds = dataSource.map(data => data.tax_id);
const legalNames = dataSource.map(data => data.legal_name);

const dataToAutoComplete = [
  { title: 'Tax IDs', data: taxIds },
  { title: 'Legal Names', data: legalNames }
];

const { Option, OptGroup } = AutoComplete;

const options = dataToAutoComplete.map(group => (
  <OptGroup key={group.title} label={group.title}>
    {group.data.map((value, i) => (
      <Option key={`${group.title}-${i}`} value={String(value)}>
        {String(value)}
      </Option>
    ))}
  </OptGroup>
));

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    value: ''
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <FlexBox>
        <AutoComplete
          value={this.state.value}
          onChange={value => {
            this.setState({ value });
          }}
          dataSource={options}
          filterOption
        />
      </FlexBox>
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Edit Q-57166866-AutoCompleteExample]